# With AngularJS 1.2, wanting ng-repeater to not create line break

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've go to speaker names I want to output wrapped in anchor tags and I want to output them in the same line (no line break).  When I do the code below, it wraps each in a  which causes a line break in my paragraph I'm trying to output.  How can I get a "raw" ng-repeat, that is one that does not output  tags around the answers.

```
<tr ng-repeat="session in vm.sessions" class="ProfessionalSession">
 <td class="name">
    <div data-id="{{session.id}}">
        <div class="currentSession currentSessionVisible">
            <h3 id="sessionTitle_{{session.id}}" title="{{session.title}}">{{session.title}}</h3>
            <i>by</i>
            <div ng-repeat="speaker in session.sessionPresenters" >
                <a href="{{speaker.presenterUrl}}" class="author">{{speaker.fullName}}</a>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just realized that the answer is to use `<span>` instead of `<div>`.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: Jamal, why do you think the answer I posted is not the complete answer. It was exactly what I was looking for (and I since I asked the question, I would know that)

Comment: Peter, FYI you have to use @Jamal (with an at-sign in front of the name), otherwise he might not get the message. In any case, you probably meant to message me. Your original post was in the low quality review queue and looked like the following, which is why I thought it was not a complete answer: "*oops, just realized the answer is use instead of*". If you look at your answer's history you will see that. You will also see that Jamal fixed your post so that the html gets displayed properly.

Answer (score 2):

Just put the attribute ng-repeat in the

```
<a ng-repeat="speaker in session.sessionPresenters" href="{{speaker.presenterUrl}}" class="author">{{speaker.fullName}}</a>
```